# jQuery and jQuery Mobile : tap vs touchstart, touchend, touchmove and click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, touch

Does the [jQuery Mobile Tap](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_touch.asp)  corresponds to adding an event listener to an element like this:

```
myElement.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStartHandler, false);
```

If so, what about the remaining normal events such as `touchmove`, `touchend` and so on? I mean what is their equivalent in jQuery Mobile?

Thank you for guiding me.

Comment: Unless I'm very much mistaken, I imagine those events are made up of combinations of `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend`, already pre-designed for you so all you need to worry about is `tap`, `swipe` etc..

Comment: Really? I wish it is the case. I believe tap reproduces also the click event but I do not have the tools to test if it combines also touchstart, touchend ... thank you for your feedback @NiettheDarkAbsol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally `tap` makes use of `vclick`.

If you don't find an event in this list, they aren't exposed with the same name: https://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

This means, for example: if you need to handle touchstart, touchend and touchmove, as normally is, you will probably end up to use the set of virtualized mouse event handler: `vmousedown, vmousemove,  vmouseup` and `vclick` but you may need to handle the status of the pointer (mouse or finger) by yourself. Do not forget to handle `vmousecancel`.

Moreover, you should note that there is a delay to wait for some events.

Following is a short extract for you, from the jQuery Mobile documentation with some critical concepts for touch devices (mobile or modern hybrid laptops) to pay attention to:

> Webkit based browsers synthesize mousedown, mouseup, and click events
>   roughly 300ms after the touchend event is dispatched.
>
> The jQuery Mobile taphold triggers after 750ms.
>
> After 1500ms, then it is not a touch event. Scroll, TouchMove and
>   TouchEnd events use this. The block list is cleared.
>
> We recommend using click instead of vclick anytime the action being
>   triggered has the possibility of changing the content underneath the
>   point that was touched on screen. This includes page transitions and
>   other behaviors such as collapse/expand that could result in the
>   screen shifting or content being completely replaced.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if is exactly the same way they do the handle, but both of they wait for an action and then execute  funciton.
in jquery mobile you can do

> $("p").on("taphold",function(){
>    $(this).hide();
>   });
>   
>   and
>
> $(function(){
>    $( "div.box" ).bind( "tap", tapHandler );
>   
>    function tapHandler( event ){
>      $( event.target ).addClass( "tap" );
>    }
>   });

list of events https://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I can not upvote unfortunately but the core of my question is not answered fully. Thank you sir