# Jquery mobile and desktop bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.sitenavigation li.nav-dropdown').on('click',
  function(event) {
    if (event.stopPropagation) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
      event.cancelBubble = true;
    }

    if ($('.menu-icon').is(':visible')) {
      $(this).find('> ul').toggle();
      $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
    }
  }
);
```

I am having a problem with this code in a dropdown. This code only works in a desktop and doesn't in mobile(iphone). In android is fine.

Comment: I put mousedown touchstart, and works both in mobile and desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You have that handler looking for 'click' events, but a lot of the time mobile device browsers won't register touches as clicks. Add some extra event types to look for in that handler, like so:

```
.on('click tap'....
```

https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410485/jquery-and-jquery-mobile-tap-vs-touchstart-touchend-touchmove-and-click