# jQuery: How can I change buttons appearing on "hover", to buttons appearing on tap for mobile devices?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an Jquery accordion with as content a  container, which is set relative to the buttons that I put in there which are set absolute.

upon hovering in the video container, the videos appear. When hovering out of the container, they dissapear. All works fine for laptops/PC

Currently trying to get the buttons to appear when on a mobile screen. Of course, hover wont work, but I cannot seem to figure out how to let the buttons appear on tap and dissapear when you tap again or used one of the buttons

The code I will drop  now will be extremely rough + of course you wont see any images, but on hover you will see 2 buttons appear.

```js
  $('.video-js').add('.video-button').hover(function () {
            $('.button-visibility').css("display", "inline-block");
        }, function () {
            $(".button-visibility").css("display", "none");        
    });


    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        $('.video-js').add('.video-button').onClick( function () {
                $('.button-visibility').css("display", "inline-block");
            }, function () {
                $(".button-visibility").css("display", "none");        
        });
    }
```

```css
.video-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}


.button-visibility {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.video-play, .video-rewind, .video-check, .video-forward {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 15px 22px 15px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.video-check, .video-rewind, .video-forward {
    top: 51%;
    padding: 22px 21px;
}


.video-forward{
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.video-rewind {
    margin-left: -100px;
    padding: 22px 21px;
    
}

.video-check {
    margin-left: 200px;
    background-color:  #00FF00;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.5.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3> 
     <span> <i class="fas fa-caret-right rotate arrow"></i> Algemene       introductie </span>             
   </h3>
                            
   <div class = "video-parent">
     <video id='my-player' class="video-js" controls data-setup='{"fluid": true}'>
       <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv" type="video/ogv">
       <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm" type="video/webm">
     </video>
   <a class="video-button" id="video-play">></a>
   </div>
   
   <a class="video-button button-visibility video-rewind"> <img src="images/src/rewind%20icon.svg" alt="rewind"></a>
                                    <a class="video-button button-visibility video-forward"> <img src="images/src/forward%20icon.svg" alt="forward"></a>
                                    <a class="video-button video-check"> <img src="images/src/done%20icon.svg" alt="check"></a>
   
   
</div>

<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.5.4/video.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410485/jquery-and-jquery-mobile-tap-vs-touchstart-touchend-touchmove-and-click

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.video-js').on('tap', (function () {
            $('.button-visibility').css("display", "inline-block");
        }, function () {
            $(".button-visibility").css("display", "none");        
    });
```

Source: https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/
Also, make sure you have `jquery` and `jqueryMobile`

Comment: doesn't really seem to work for some reason. I tap the screen, but it doesn't seem to pop anything up

Comment: can you do it on a mobile simulator that has a debug output ? Maybe it is throwing an error. How does it behave if you do it on the chrome simulator for mobile devices ? have you tried the link @mplungjan provided ?

Comment: Comming back to you: I want to thank you again for the help. Appreciate it.

However after a full day of testing and trying I decided to take a more "simpler route". I put the buttons under the video. created a class .button-visibility.hover and changed the ```.css``` to ```.addClass``` and ```.removeClass```. Reason being because it would bug out if i'd press the check mark in video and swap to desktop or vice versa.

I also added ```if  ($(window).width() > 786 ) {} ``` and put my jQuery code in there, so that if the window width would get lower than 786 it would display the buttons

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a work-around than a solution.

after a full day of testing and trying and being on a time-crunch I decided to take a more "simpler route". I put the buttons under the video. created a class .button-visibility.hover and changed the `.css` to `.addClass` and `.removeClass`. Reason being because it would bug out if i'd press the check mark in video and swap to desktop or vice versa.

I also added `if  ($(window).width() > 786 ) {}` and put my jQuery code in there, so that if the window width would get lower than 786px it would display the buttons under the video as I anticipated to happen.